# Get Tumblr posts with certain tags

Tags: api, tumblr

I need to only get tumblr posts which have been tagged with 'diary'

Here is the feed, 'http://clintonbeattie.tumblr.com/api/read/json'

I'm not sure how to loop through the posts and output only the diary ones.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the api v2 to extract only tag you need

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/clintonbeattie.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=PyezS3Q4Smivb24d9SzZGYSuhMNPQUhMsVetMC9ksuGPkK1BTt&tag=diary
```

From the doc: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts

Comment: Great. Thanks, but how would I consume that feed with JQuery?

Comment: Can't access that URL with $.getJSON "GET request Cancelled". Also can't use http://clintonbeattie.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?tag=london